# Forgot to remove blanks from IBAN

Tags: money-transfer, transfer, iban, swift

I've forgotten to delete the spaces in IBAN while sending money via swift.I checked the MT 103-single customer credit transfer paper, Everything is just correct but the blanks.(No missing digits only grouped.But my own IBAN is written without blanks.)Is this possibly going to cause a problem?

My bank is ING and receiver is ABN AMRO.

Answer (score 1):

Extremely unlikely.

Many IBAN input fields are fine with grouped/spaced IBANs. 
Those that are not will complain they'd then not have a valid IBAN there: form would not be as required (for input fields that cut off the last digits because characters are taken up by the spaces) and the IBAN contains check digits to guard against typos that would lead to the IBAN being invalid unless the grouped input is treated correctly.
Worst case, the transfer was silently not started - which you can easily check: did the money actually leave your account?

Comment: Yes, it has left my account.Thanks a lot for your answer!